# Codeigniter 3 - subdirectory controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have one issue related to how to add controllers in sub directories for a better administration of large amount of files
For that, I have the following structure in controllers:

```
controllers
--admin
----projects
--------block.php
----projects.php
----dashboard.php
```

If I'm heading to `admin/projects` the controller works just fine, but if I want to select `admin/projects/block` it doesn't work at all, generating a 404 page

I even tried to change the route.php using:

```
$route['admin/projects/block/(:any)']       = 'admin/projects/block/$1';
```

Am I doing something wrong? Do you have any idea?

Comment: The recommended pattern is Controller/method/ID. But then, it is your preference how you handle your routing. By the way, have you tried, `admin/projects/block/sampletext` ? I expect that you should have a value after the `block/` based on your routing.

Comment: I did try out to call a method within the block controller, but.. I guess that Codeigniter wants to access a method from projects controller that actually represents a diferent controller..

Comment: Can you rename your controller name. The first letter of your controller MUST be capital letter. Also the controller class name should start with capital letter `<?php class Block extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: the controllers are indeed with capital letters but here for comodity i skipped that part

Comment: admin/projects/block will be looking for a block method in your projects controller... As you ALSO have a folder called projects - which do you expect CI to determine what you are talking about... Rename one of the "projects" things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing something wrong. The correct url format is: SITE_ROOT/CONTROLLER/ACTION

So when you go to admin/projects/block << it's trying to go to the block function of the projects controller.

You'll need to override routing to do what you're trying to do.